# Find_SRID and SQL error statement showing different SRID's for the same column

Tags: postgis

the Find_SRID function shows 0 for column 'route'

whereas when I try to run KNN as

```
routes.route <-> pc.point_geom AS dist
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: ST_Distance: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (LineString, 4326) != (Point, 0)
```

Clearly the error shows that the linestring column has SRID = 4326, which is different to what the Find_SRID shows above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the SRID of a column, you can use the [ST_SRID](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SRID.html) function. [Find_SRID](https://postgis.net/docs/Find_SRID.html) is a little different, it will look for the SRID in the `GEOMETRY_COLUMNS` view, which is not always filled when you create a geometry column. To reference a column in this table, which is used by several other tools (like QGIS I think, and others...) to look for geometry fields in your database, you need to use the function [AddGeometryColumn](https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html).